# Writing a script to upload files into iRODS, do I write this in Python and incorporate iRODS commands?

Tags: python, shell, command-line

iRODS documentation: https://docs.irods.org/4.2.0/icommands/user/

I need to create directory structures in iRODS. I have a script in Python that creates directories on my computer, but how do I edit this script so that it creates directory structures in iRODS and moves the files into these directories? Do I incorporate iRODS commands into a Python script? Not sure how this will exactly work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Python script to make calls to iRODS to create collections.

The easiest way to do this will be through the Python iRODS Client:

https://github.com/irods/python-irodsclient

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-irodsclient
```

> Create a new collection:
>
> ```
>    >>> coll = sess.collections.create("/tempZone/home/rods/testdir")
>    >>> coll.id
>    45799
> ```

And then you can put files into iRODS:

```
https://github.com/irods/python-irodsclient#reading-and-writing-files
```

Comment: Great thank you so much. I downloaded the Python iRODS Client, is there anything else I need to do to incorporate calls to iRODS in my script? (E.g. and import statement at the top of my script)

Comment: just `from irods.session import iRODSSession` and then `sess = iRODSSession(host='localhost', port=1247, user='rods', password='rods', zone='tempZone')`